# How to add source code to .dll file in Visual Studio Express 2012?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, debugging, dll

I have a 3rd party .dll file and its source code as well ( written in C# ). I can create a new project and add reference of this .dll file to use its methods. But when I debug I want to step in to the methods defined in .dll file ( Just like we do when we have .jar file and its source-code in java ).

How can I do this in Visual Studio Express ( I have VS 2012 ).

Comment: When you attempt to step into a method, does VS not prompt you for a source file?  It seems to do that for me.

Comment: I don't think it will work the way you are describing. Your best bet (IMO) would be to create a new project from the DLL's source code. POSSIBLE (maybe?) to attach to the process that runs the DLL and somehow link that to the source code, but I have never seen that done.

Comment: Do you not have the pdb for your 3rd party dll?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The easiest, if you have the source code, would be to add the project to your solution and compile both at the same time. You could then breakpoint everywhere! (And don't you dare tell me breakpoint isn't a verb)